# A generator expression fails with maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion, generator, python-2.x

Consider the following code snippet (Note I was using global because nonlocal keywords is not available in Python 2.7)

```
def foo(L,K):
    global count
    count = 0
    def bar(f,L):
        global count
        for  e in L:
            if e - f == K or f - e == K: count += 1
            yield e
    try:
        while True:
            L = bar(L.next(),L)
    except StopIteration:
        return count
count=0
print foo((int(e) for e in some_string.split()),some_number)
```

where

```
some_string: A space delimited integers
some_number: An integer
```

when `len(some_string) = 4000`, the above code fails with the error

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Is it because internally nested generators are implemented as recursion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are replacing `L`, with the result of `bar`, which is a generator itself. Thus, you end up passing `bar` back to `bar` in the form of recursively nested generator expressions.

This construction eventually passes the recursion depth limits.